# $O_{KL} \subset \frac{1}{d}O_KO_L$ where $d = \text{gcd}(disc(O_K),disc(O_L))$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, extension-field

Let $L,K$ be number fields such that $L\cap K =\mathbb{Q}$ then $O_{KL} \subset \frac{1}{d}O_KO_L$ where $d = \text{gcd}(disc(O_K),disc(O_L))$